# How to control continuous requests to server using javascript while displaying images

Tags: javascript, html

I am editing a code snippet I found for displaying a slideshow of images stored on the server. I checked the inspect window on browser and under network tab and I found it is continuously making GET requests to the server. Is it okay to keep a continuous connection with the server. Is there any other way to do it ?

The code written accesses images that are stored as 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg and displays them in a slideshow.

```
<img id="image" src="localhost/1.jpg" style="width: 800px; height: 800px" />
<br />
<input type="button" value="Start Slide Show" onclick="startImageSlideShow()" />
<input type="button" value="Stop Slide Show" onclick="stopImageSlideShow()" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  function stopImageSlideShow() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }

  function setImage() {
    var imageSrc = document.getElementById("image").getAttribute("src");
    var currentImageNumber = imageSrc.substring(imageSrc.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
      imageSrc.lastIndexOf("/") + 2);
    if (currentImageNumber == 3) {
      currentImageNumber = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src", "http://localhost/" +
      (Number(currentImageNumber) + 1) + ".jpg");
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pre load your images

```
function preloadImage(url)
{
   var img=new Image();
   img.src=url;
}
```

Otherwise continuous requests are okay!

Comment: My images will be changing after certain intervals and so will be the url to access them depending on the name that I get from the server. So its better to keep the continuos requests on right ?

Comment: yes. if you dont have the list of images then you are left with this option.